# c pipe ls returned strings to parent

Tags: c, pipe, execv

I'm currently trying to run an ls command in my C code and then pipe the outputted strings to the parent process via a fd.

The problem I'm currently facing is, that I execv the ls command but I don't know how to store the strings (if that is even necessary) and then pipe them to my parent process and execute another command with the given input like I wrote in the comment. Is there also a way to block the ls output to the terminal in my child process?

```
int main(void)
{

   int fd1[2]; // Used to store two ends of first pipe
   int fd2[2]; // Used to store two ends of second pipe

   pid_t p;

   p = fork(); // Now forking to create a child

   // Parent process
   else if (p > 0)
   {    
      close(fd1[0]); // Close reading end of first pipe

      // Wait for child to send the strings
      wait(NULL);

      close(fd2[1]); // Close writing end of second pipe

      // Read strings from child, print it and close
      // reading end.
      read(fd2[0], "", 100);
      close(fd2[0]);
      // todo another command like "wc -l" and print the result to the terminal with write 

   }
   // Child process
   else
   {
      close(fd1[1]); // Close writing end of first pipe

      // execute ls command and send the strings to the parent
      int status;
      char *args[2];

      args[0] = "/bin/ls";        // first arg is the full path to the executable
      args[1] = NULL;             // list of args must be NULL terminated

      execv( args[0], args );     // child: call execv with the path and the args
      
      // Close both reading ends
      close(fd1[0]);
      close(fd2[0]);

      // write the strings to the parent
      write(fd2[1], "", strlen("") + 1);
      close(fd2[1]);

      exit(0);
   }

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I'm sorry if this is a silly question, but I'm very new to forking and using pipes.

Comment: Where are the pipes created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, must call [`pipe`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) on an `int [2]` to create a pipe. You have not done this.

---

In the parent process:

This [`read`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) call

```
read(fd2[0], "", 100);
```

does not make sense. `""` is a read-only, `char [1]`. Trying to store data in it will invoke [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

You need a reasonably sized buffer (array) to store the data you read in. Additionally, you should check if any data was actually read by testing the return value of [`read`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html), which is the number of bytes read.

Remember that this data is not null terminated - it is raw bytes, not a string. If you want to treat it as a string, you need to null terminate the buffer manually (make sure to leave room).

---

In the child process:

To redirect the standard output of `ls` to be the write end of the pipe, instead of the terminal, [`dup2`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html) is used:

[`dup2`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html) makes the file descriptor specified by its second argument refer to the same *file description* as its first argument.

The code after [`execv`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) makes little sense, as [`execv`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) *never returns* if it succeeds. You should close any unnecessary file descriptors before this point, and only handle failure states afterwards.

---

A cursory example of all this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    int my_pipe[2];

    if (pipe(my_pipe)) {
        perror("pipe");
        return 1;
    }

    if (fork()) {
        ssize_t bytes;
        char buffer[512];

        close(my_pipe[1]);

        while ((bytes = read(my_pipe[0], buffer, sizeof buffer - 1)) > 0) {
            buffer[bytes] = 0;
            printf("Parent got:\n%s\n", buffer);
        }

        close(my_pipe[0]);

        wait(NULL);
    } else {
        char *args[] = {
            "/bin/ls",
            NULL
        };

        close(my_pipe[0]);
        dup2(my_pipe[1], fileno(stdout));
        close(my_pipe[1]);

        execv(args[0], args);

        /* we only get here if execv fails */
        perror("execv");
    }
}
```